# hi i am not getting data from my one method to other in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

hi i am new to android and working on android alarm app in that i am not able to get the data when i set the time it should be inserted in the database. i tried but i am getting null at the end. am not able to insert data in to my sqlite database table. Please help me to solve this thank you in advance.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            // calSet.set(Calendar.MILL ISECOND, 0);

            if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
                // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
            // SQLiteDatabase mDB = null;
            AlarmActivity mDbHelper;

            // clearAll();
            insertalarmclock();
            Cursor c = readalarm();
            // mAdapter = ;

            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            onChecked(calSet);
            setAlarm(calSet);
        }

        private void insertalarmclock() {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(this.KEY_HOUR, "Hour");
            mDB.insert(this.KEY_HOUR, null, values);

            values.clear();

            values.put(this.KEY_MINUTE, "minute");
            mDB.insert(this.KEY_MINUTE, null, values);

            values.clear();
        }

        // private void clearAll() {
        // SQLiteDatabase mDB = null;
        // mDB.delete(MyDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        //
        // }
        private Cursor readalarm() {
            return mDB.query(this.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, this.minutes, null,
                    new String[] {}, null, null, null);
        }

    });
```

Comment: From which method to which method you are sending data?

Comment: oh sorry with my english please check the question once again please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass parameters in a function:

```
private void insertalarmclock(int hour, int minute) {
    //Save to database
}
```

And call as

```
insertalarmclock(hour, minute);
```

If you are getting null even after this, debug and check what's issue.

Where are the variables declared? And are they assigned any values?